# Navigation in a Silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I recently got myself into Silverlight and I'm trying to develop an application where it reads data from XML.

My problem is that I have never understood how to actually navigate/make views visible/hidden/collapsed depending on what button the client is clicking. In example, this project reads the menu structure from a XML file and I'm using an ItemsControl to display the menuitems like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="900" Height="40"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Tag="{Binding Url}" Content="{Binding Name}" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

This code is in my MenuView.xaml (I'm using MVVM by the way) and on my MainPage.xaml I've included the MenuView like this:

```
<views:MenuView x:Name="menu" />
```

Now, when a user click one of the buttons, I need to show the correct view on my mainpage. The tricky thing (for me at least) is, that the content from the XML file is "of-type", so basically I have these views:

- TextPageView
- NewsPageView

Where the NewsPageView's layout is different than the TextPageView, which is just a regular textpage really.

How exactly should I be navigating/hiding/showing these views **without** using the navigation framework? :-)

Hope my question is clear, if not - please let me know and I will try to elaborate!

Thanks in advance.

All the best,

Bo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Navigation Framework is your friend :)

Comment: I'm curious as to why this was marked as answer? The OP stated he didn't want to use the NF.